# Pass 3 values in highcharts series

Tags: javascript, function, variables, highcharts, scatter-plot

I have a scatter chart from Highcharts, in the y axis i put 'Intensity' values,and in the x axis i have datetimes (month,day,year).

```
chart: {
  type: 'scatter',
  zoomType: 'xy',
  renderTo: 'chartContainer'
},
rangeSelector: {
  enabled: true
},
xAxis: {
  title: {
    enabled: true
  },
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats:{
    month: '%e. %b %Y',
    year: '%b'
  },
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true,
  showLastLabel: true
},
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: 'Intensity'
  },
  min: 0,
  max: 100
},
plotOptions: {
  scatter: {
    marker: {
      radius: 5,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true,
          lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
        }
      }
    },
    states: {
      hover: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    events: {
      click: function(event) {

        showMoreData();


      }
    }
  }
},
series: [{
  name: 'Male',
  color: 'rgba(144,36,58, .8)',
  data: getDataParsed()
}]
```

These data are loaded from another function `getDataParsed()`, where I do a ajax GET and get multiple data . The question is how i pass more data (also Intensity and Datetimes) so i can used later in the scatter chart.

```
function getDataParsed() {

var serie = [];

var i=0;
dolorCollect.forEach(function (dato) {


var arr = dato.FECHA_INICIO.split("/");
var hour = dato.HORA_INICIO.split(":");

serie[i]=     [Date.UTC(arr[2],arr[1]-1,arr[0],hour[0],hour[1]),dato.INTENSIDAD_DOLOR];


i++;

});

return serie;

}
```

Comment: There are three formats for points in a series: (1) `[yValue1, yValue2,...yValueN]` when you have the categories set (2) `[[xValue1, yValue1], [xValue2, yValue2],...[xValueN, yValueN]]` which is what you are using and (3) `[{name: name1, x: x1, y: y1}, {name: name2, x: x2, y: y2},...{name: nameN, x: xN, y: yN}]`. In the third each point is an object with it's own configuration settings (name, color etc.). In this format you can add custom properties which can later be used by the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have more data in each data point in series' data you can:

1. do as **Rahul Sharma** suggested in his comment - set data point as object with named properties. More info in [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.data) - see 3rd way of data format:

> An array of objects with named values. The objects are point configuration objects as seen below. If the total number of data points exceeds the series' turboThreshold, this option is not available.
>
> ```
> data: [{
>     x: 1,
>     y: 2,
>     name: "Point2",
>     color: "#00FF00"
> }, {
>     x: 1,
>     y: 4,
>     name: "Point1",
>     color: "#FF00FF"
> }]
> ```

2. or set data as array of arrays - as you do now, but with more data in point array. To allow Highcharts proper way to decode your new format set [keys](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.keys).

So same data can be set using code like:

```
series:[{
  data: [
    [1, 2, "Point2", "#00FF00"], 
    [1, 4, "Point1", "#FF00FF"]
  ],
  keys: ['x','y','name','color'],
  ...
```